# WPF: use the same xaml file with different codebehinds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a wpf program that needs several usercontrols that look exactly the same but perform different functions. With winForms, I could just extend the base control and add the functionality, but as far as I know, it's impossible to inherit xaml files. Is there any way I can have different codebehind classes that all use the same xaml file for their control?

Comment: Maybe another approach would be better, create the minimum code possible on the control and create different classes with the control's behavior, when you instantiate the form then choose which behavioral class to use..

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using MVVM pattern and create multiple VMs which perhaps implement the same interface.  The XAML view could then be bound to any of your VMs relying on the fact they share the same interface.

In this approach you'd not use the code behind at all.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using inheritance. A very simple example would be a `UserControl` with a single button, that should display different contents in a `MessageBox`.

We will have something like this:

```
public abstract class SomeUserControl : UserControl 
{
   //declared by XAML (can be made public with x:FieldModifier="public")
   public Button MyButton;

   //code-behind 
   public SomeUserControl() {
       InitializeComponent();
   }     
}

public class MySpecialControl : SomeUserControl {
      public MySpecialControl() {
         MyButton.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Bla");
      }      
}
```

To use the `MySpecialControl`, just declare it in XAML like you did with your previous one:

```
<myNamespace:MySpecialControl />
```

Note that you can also create an abstract method for the button click, if the variation in behavior is not so big.

Answer (score 0):

> With winForms, I could just extend the base control

And one can't do similar in WPF?

Create a custom composite control with a dependency property(ies) which would set the *mode* of the control to fit its the target consumer's needs.

The control could be based on an existing control or controls.